# How to use pandas calculate error percentage (groupby)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, lambda, percentage

[image]

Hi, I have a dataframe which has date information. I want to calculate the error rate for the CampainAction Date (this Campaign date should be prior than today's date. If it is later than today's date, it is wrong!!) and groupby the country.

Can anyone tell me how to calculate the error percentage% using lambda or any Pandas function?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what do you want to do with the columns without a `Date`? Assume they are always valid, or not valid, or exclude them from the error rate?

Comment: I believe exclude those missing values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your dates to a `datetime`, then create a boolean column that indicates whether or not it's an error. Then just `groupby` + `mean` to get the percentage.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create datetimes.
df['CampaignAction Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CampaignAction Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Today'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Today'], errors='coerce')

# Create an Error column
mask = df['CampaignAction Date'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Error_per'] = (df.loc[mask,'CampaignAction Date'] >= df.loc[mask, 'Today']).astype(float)

df.groupby('Country').Error_per.mean().reset_index()
```

Output: (for the first two countries)

```
  Country  Error_per
0  Brazil        0.5
1   China        0.2
```

---

Here's some sample data:

```
  Country CampaignAction Date      Today
0   China           5/20/2018  9/20/2018
1   China           6/30/2018  9/20/2018
2   China           1/30/2018  9/20/2018
3   China           3/30/2018  9/20/2018
4   China                      9/20/2018
5   China          10/31/2018  9/20/2018
6  Brazil           6/30/2018  9/20/2018
7  Brazil           5/21/2019  9/20/2018
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!It helps